# Calling objective-c method from javascript using JSCore

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I try to call objC method from UIWebView using JavaScriptCore. And it doesn't work. I can see that `window.objc` is assigned correctly. Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"></html>" baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    JSContext *context = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
    context[@"objc"] = self;
    NSString *javaScript = @"function test() {  \
                         window.objc.callObjc();\
                         }";
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test();"];
}

- (void)callObjc
{
    NSLog(@"this doesn't work");
}
```

I know it's going to work if I inject the method like this:

```
context[@"test"] = ^(void) {
    [self callObjc];
};
```

but I have a javascript file with a number of methods already implemented (reusing javascript created for android), so I want to minimize objC code.

Comment: UIWebView doesn't do JSCore. You're combining apples with oranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to enable direct communication from JS to ObjC I need to create a protocol inherited from JSExport and put all the methods I want to be accessible from JSContext in that protocol:

```
@protocol JSBridge <JSExport>
    - (void)callObjc;
@end
```

Obviously need to make sure my view controller conforms to that protocol and I'm all set.

Info taken from [here](http://hayageek.com/execute-javascript-in-ios/).